# why select helper does not auto show the selected value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This code works:

```
select("questionnaire", "is_active", options_for_select([["no", false], ["yes", true]], @questionnaire.is_active) )
```

But this will not:

```
select("questionnaire", "is_active", options_for_select([["no", false], ["yes", true]]) )
```

Why doesn't rails know to handle the selected value by itself? What's the logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are calling the helper directly without the form object:

```
<%= select(:questionnaire, :is_active, ......) %>
```

You should call it on a form for that object:

```
<%= form_for @questionnaire do |form| %>
  <%= form.select(:is_active, [["no", false], ["yes", true]]) %>
```

You don't really need `options_for_select` in this case, the select helper will call that with the propper selected value.